# Clojure transients usage

Tags: clojure

I'm a bit lost with usage of transients in clojure. Any help will be appreciated.
The sample code:

```
(defn test-transient [v]
    (let [b (transient [])]
        (for [x v] (conj! b x))
        (persistent! b)))

user> (test-transient [1 2 3])
[]
```

I tried to make it persistent before return and the result is:

```
(defn test-transient2 [v]
    (let [b (transient [])]
        (for [x v] (conj! b x))
        (persistent! b)
        b))

user> (test-transient2 [1 2 3])
#<TransientVector clojure.lang.PersistentVector$TransientVector@1dfde20>
```

But if I use conj! separately it seems work ok:

```
(defn test-transient3 [v]
    (let [b (transient [])]
    (conj! b 0)
    (conj! b 1)
    (conj! b 2)
    (persistent! b)))

user> (test-transient3 [1 2 3])
[0 1 2]
```

Does for has some constraint? If so, how can i copy values from persistent vector to transient?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transients aren't supposed to be bashed in-place like that. Your last example only works due to implementation details which you shouldn't rely on.

The reason why `for` doesn't work is that it is lazy and the `conj!` calls are never executed, but that is besides the point, as you shouldn't work with transients that way anyway.

You should use `conj!` the same way as you would use the "regular" `conj` with immutable vectors - by using the return value.

What you are trying to do could be accomplished like this:

```
(defn test-transient [v]
  (let [t (transient [])]
    (persistent! (reduce conj! t v))))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I'm still confused. In this case I don't see big difference between my usage of _for_ and the example from clojure web site:


`(defn vrange2 [n]
  (loop [i 0 v (transient [])]
    (if (< i n)
      (recur (inc i) (conj! v i))
      (persistent! v))))`

Comment: that recur expression passes the *value* of conj! back into the loop. For expressions don't work that way.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thank you and appreciated. :)